# Send Email using gmail Smtp not working ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, smtp

I am working on an application in which I want to send verification emails using SMTP Gmail. Although my less secure app is turned on but is still no email received. But when I send an email on order confirmation it is sending email without any block. SMTP is already installed on the windows server. It is working fine on local but when making deployment only user for registration is not working. Though when a user confirms an order then the email is sent properly. Here is my code

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = UtilConfiguration._config["EmailConfigurations-Gmail:Host"],
                Port = Convert.ToInt32(UtilConfiguration._config["EmailConfigurations-Gmail:Port"]),
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UtilConfiguration._config["EmailConfigurations-Gmail:Email"], UtilConfiguration._config["EmailConfigurations-Gmail:Password"]),
                EnableSsl = true,
                Timeout = 10000
            };
```

My local deployment is HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: Are you trying to send the email with Gmail SMTP? Please check the less secure apps option. Even if you turn on this, sometimes it is turned off automatically. And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I have checked every time I sent an email. It might be some issue on the server end as I am using live IP for my portal to access

Comment: Okay. It is nothing to do with your code. It is about Gmail. This might take some time to apply the less secure apps setting.